# Node js mongodb group

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my history model. It contains three fields:Content,Year,Month
  sample data like:

```
 1 "aaaaa",2012,12
 2 "bbbbb",2013,11
 3 "ccccc",2012,09
```

I want to group by "Year" field,and store like this:

```
[{"aaaaa",2012,12}},{"ccccc",2012,09}],
[{"bbbbb",2013,11}],
```

Here is my code:

```
// index.js   
var hisArrs = [];

History.distinct("Year", function(err, doc) {
  var years = doc;

  years.forEach(function(year) {
    History.find({"Year": year}, function(err, docs){
      hisArrs.push(docs);
    });
  }); 
});

res.render('History/history', {
  title: 'history',
  HisArrs: hisArrs
});
```

However, I don't understand why. Could you please help on this?

Comment: Your first problem is that both `distinct` and `find` are asynchronous.  You must wait for their callbacks to complete before trying to render the results.

Comment: @numbers1311407 thank u for u answer.i had tried async.js waterfall,but i still cant not store the result that i want it.could u leave me your email,so i cant explain detail.